# Rig vs bimonoidal categories

Tags: probability-theory, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I was wondering if rig categories (as discussed here [ncatlab: rig category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category) for example), are the same thing as bimonoidal categories (as discussed here [Bimonoidal Structure of Probability Monads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03527)
 for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nlab page explicitly states that bimonoidal category is another name for rig categories. But in the paper you link, a bimonoidal structure is some structure which you can put **on a monad**, consisting of a monoidal and an opmonoidal structure which are compatible with each other (see section 3). These are entirely different concepts (there might be a connection since categories are just monads in the bicategory of spans, but I doubt that). In fact, the paper does not even mention "bimonoidal categories".